# Different design if user is logged with twig embed on Symfony

Tags: symfony, twig

I am creating a new project, and on my main page design, I need to show 2 columns if the user is a guest, and 3 columns if the user is logged.

Ok, I am trying to do it with the `embed` function on Twig, but I only can make it work duplicating html code without the 'embed' Twig function (so bad technique ... ).

This are my templates:

**index.html.twig**

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
    {% block body %}
        {% embed "home_columns" %}
            {% if is_granted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY") %}
                    3 columns
            {% else %}
                    2 columns
            {% endif %}
        {% endembed %}
{% endblock %}
```

**home_columns.html.twig**

```
{% block main_left_col %}
    <aside id="left_column" class="col-md-2">&nbsp;</aside>
{% endblock %}

{% block main_middle %}
    <section id="last-plans" class="col-md-8"></section>
{% endblock %}

{% block main_right_col %}
    <aside id="right_column" class="col-md-2">&nbsp;</aside>
{% endblock %}
```

But it is now working ...

**Is the *embed* twig function the best way to do what I want?**

Comment: I think the embed function is the right way to go. This link explains the difference between `embed`, `include` and `macro`: https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/1697

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the real problem is this part of code:

```
    {% if is_granted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY") %}
        3 columns
    {% else %}
        2 columns 
        {% block main_right_col %}{% endblock %}
    {% endif %}
```

Which returns this error:

```
    An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template         
    ("Node "1" does not exist for Node "Twig_Node".") in         
    "HomeBundle:Default:index.html.twig".
```

It seems to be that i can't check if user is logged from the embed twig template.

In the view:

```
    {% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

    {% block body %}

        {% embed "HomeBundle:Default:home_columns.html.twig" with { 'userIsLogged': is_granted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY") } %}

        {% endembed %}

    {% endblock %}
```

And in the embeded view:

```
    {% if userIsLogged == true %}

        3 columns

    {% else %}

        2 columns 

    {% endif %}
```

Regards!

Comment: Did you try to use `with {'userIsLogged': is_granted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY")}`? It looks like the `userIsLogged` value is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks, you were right!. userIsLogged value was not necessary.